# Strange error using XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Only in some cases, i've this error calling and XPage

```
java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Cookie name "some name" is a reserved token
```

What could be the cause? How to resolve this?

**UPDATE**

this is the full error row inside `error-log-0.xml`

```
<values>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie name &quot;Urbanistica e    
Verde&amp;count&quot; is a reserved token&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.Throwable.&lt;init&gt;
(Throwable.java:67)&#xA;&#x9;at javax.servlet.http.Cookie.&lt;init&gt;
(Cookie.java:128)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdHttpServletRequest.parseCookieString (XspCmdHttpServletRequest.java:338)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdHttpServletRequest.getCookies(XspCmdHttpServletRequest.java:269)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdHttpServletRequest.readSessionId(XspCmdHttpServletRequest.java:171)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdHttpServletRequest.&lt;init&gt;(XspCmdHttpServletRequest.java:142)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:256)&#xA;</values>
```

**UPDATE 2**

XSP has this SSJS in `afterPageLoad` event

```
var cgi = new CGIVariables();
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response = exCon.getResponse();
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);

com.xxx.MyClass.myMethod(
    facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest(), 
    response
);

facesContext.responseComplete();
```

`CGIVariables` is a Server Javascript function (see [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpages-cgi-variables.htm)), but actually is not used.
In `myMethod` inside `MyClass` i don't set cookies. Could be the problem in `CGIVariables` function?

**UPDATE 3**
I've made some screenshot about traffic network (with IE development tool), with the requests made.
Here the requests:

[image]

Here the details about a request:

[image]

Here the details about cookies sent (as you can see, there are no cookies with the reserved name, the string `Urbanistica e Verde` is in the **value** of one of the cookies -> see the red line)
[image]

**UPDATE 4**

Problem seems related to `the cookie value`, not to `the cookie name`. Deleting ',' character in cookie value solve the problem

Comment: What is the value of "some name"? Some cookie names may be reserved.

Comment: error-log-0.xml has this error: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie name "Urbanistica e Verde&count" is a reserved token". I don't know why "&count" is put into cookie name....

Comment: The problem is not the "&count", the issue is the white space in the name. See the answer below

Comment: You say "In some cases..." you get this error. What are the cases? Find the difference between the cases that work and the cases that don't. That will help you narrow down where the illegal cookie name is being set. Also, is the string "Urbanistica e Verde" part of your application, part of the data a user is entering?

Comment: Yes it is a part of data. But i don't understand why calling the XPage a cookie with that name is set. XPage is invoked by an HTML page through an Ajax request (via button)....

Comment: If you bring up the HTML page and use your browser's feature to examine headers, cookies, etc., do you see the cookie? And if so, what is the value? Maybe that will give some sort of hint about how/why it's being set.

Comment: Yes, i see cookie values. But i don't see a cookie with that name..

Comment: In UPDATE 3 more information about the network traffic

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are using an illegal name.

From [this website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html),

```
The name must conform to RFC 2965. That means it can contain only ASCII alphanumeric characters and
cannot contain commas, semicolons, or **white space** or begin with a $ character.
```

There are also other characters that cannot be used.

Comment: How can I control the cookie name? Basically, i'm using an xsp that call some Java code (like a servlet), so i don't understand how the cookie is generated.

Comment: Then your first step is to see where the cookie is created.  You should look in javascript code, in the java code, and the xpage itself.

Comment: Some other details in *UPDATE 2*

Comment: I try to remove CGIVariables but nothing changed

Comment: I don't have a cookie with a reserved name. See UPDATE 3 for more informations